# Is this the correct format of Command Object..?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

```
    Public Function GET_B(ByVal CampusCode As String) As DataSet

        Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString)

        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = "SELECT BldgCode "
        strSQL += "FROM BuildingPublicExt "
        strSQL += "WHERE (CampusCode = N'" & "@CampusCode" & "') "
        strSQL += "AND (BldgStatusCode = N'A') "
        strSQL += "ORDER BY BldgCode"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CampusCode", CampusCode)

        Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd, objConn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ad.Fill(ds, "Result")

        Return ds
        objConn.Close()
    End Function
```

Is format of "`Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL)`" is correct..? Or do I need to add any connection object in parameters..

Comment: Does your code work?  If so then what you have done is OK.  If not then say so and tell us what actually DOES happen.  Don't be mysterious.

Comment: Is  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL) the correct format....?
Or i need to add connection object..
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL,objConn)

What shall i do...

Comment: I can see on issue.  You should learn how to use parameters properly.  This: `strSQL += "WHERE (CampusCode = N'" & "@CampusCode" & "') "`, should be this: `strSQL += "WHERE (CampusCode = @CampusCode) "`.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Don't just ask the same question again when two people have already told you that that question is inadequate.  You're not going to make any friends here like that.  If you have an issue then explain the issue.  WHY are you asking that question?  If it works then why would you think it's wrong?  If it doesn't work then say that and explain what does happen.  If you're unable to do that then I think this programming thing might be beyond you.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney I have used 'N' as I nedd to pass unicode data.... 
Actually I am not able to run the program as I am asked to see if there is any wrong in code... I will be happy if you point out a few mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `SqlConnection` object as second parameter`in`constructor`of`SqlCommand`.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL,objConn);
```

If you do this than there is no need to pass `SqlConnection` object in `constructor` of `SqlDataAdapter`.

```
Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd); //Remove objConn from here.
```

If you pass `SqlConnection` object in `SqlAdapter constructor` than first agrument should be of type `string` which will be your query.